# Spark Submit spark.local.dir setting not working when submitting jobs through YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We are trying to run Spark Submit job and we noticed that Spark Scratch Directories are created in `/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin` when we use the following command to run Spark Submit jobs through YARN. We don't have access to create temp  directories in `/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin`. So we are trying to set the temp dir path with a folder we have write access using the conf property `spark.local.dir`.

```
./spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.runners.spark.examples.WordCount --master yarn --conf "spark.local.dir=/hadoop/landingzone/" /hadoop/landingzone/beam-runners-spark-bundled-spark.jar --runner=SparkRunner --inputFile=/hadoop/landingzone/pom.xml --output=counts
```

Exception Received:

```
IOException because we don't have write access to /opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin directory.
```

Warning Message:

```
In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN)
```

Could you please guide how to set scratch directory path when submitting jobs through YARN as `spark.local.dir` setting is not working.

Thanks